# Create a new Magento Status

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, backend, magento2.3.1, magento2.3.4

I want to create a new Magento Status in the backend using Data Patch. Anyone having any idea on how to process that?

Thanks,
Rashi

Comment: new order status ? @Rashi Goyal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create new order status and state follow below steps:

1.Create folder Setup/Patch/Data in your module

2.Create file UpdateOrderStatuses.php

3.Implement method apply in the class UpdateOrderStatuses

4.Run bin/magento setup:upgrade

> [Vendor]/[Module]/Setup/Patch/Data/UpdateOrderStatuses.php

```
<?php
  namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Setup\Patch\Data;

  use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

  class UpdateOrderStatuses implements DataPatchInterface
  {
     /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    public function __construct(
   \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
    ) {
      $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    }

   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
   */
   public function apply()
   {
   // Insert statuses
   // use insertOnDuplicate(), insertArray() etc here
   $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->insertOnDuplicate(
       $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('sales_order_status'),
       ['status' => 'dispatched', 'label' => 'Dispatch']
   );

   //Bind status to state
   $states = [
       [
           'status'     => 'dispatched',
           'state'      => 'dispatched',
           'is_default' => 0,
       ],
       [
           'status'     => 'dispatched',
           'state'      => 'complete',
           'is_default' => 0,
       ],
       [
           'status'     => 'dispatched',
           'state'      => 'closed',
           'is_default' => 0,
       ],
   ];
   foreach ($states as $state) {
       $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->insertOnDuplicate(
           $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('sales_order_status_state'),
           $state
       );
   }
}

/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
  public static function getDependencies()
  {
    return [];
  }


  public function getAliases()
  {
   return [];
  }
 }
```